# Mapping over an array, and I'm trying to alter the "color" parameter of a Bootstrap button based on response

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx, reactstrap

(Project is React using Axios and react-strap)

I have an array from an API that returns the following example information:

```
      {
        "$type": "Example",
        "id": 0,
        "statusSeverity": 10,
        "statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "validityPeriods": [
          
        ]
      }
    ],
```

I'm attempting to set the "color" type of a Bootstrap button within React based on the "statusSeverityDescription" result. Trying the following ternary operation to assign it as btn-success for "Good Service", and btn-warning for anything else:

```
{lineStatuses.map(status =>
  <Button
    style ={{color : status.statusSeverityDescription === "Good Service" ? 'btn-success' : 'warning' }}
  >
  <h4>{status.statusSeverityDescription}</h4>

  </Button>
)}
```

The H4 text displays as normal, so it is getting the information from lineStatuses, but the buttons emerge as "btn-secondary" by default it seems. Also, looking at props of the button in React dev, it says that "style" has {color:"btn-success"}. It seems it would work if I could remote the style attribute, but it seems something has to be there.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Instead of setting style, you should set the className property

Comment: I have tried that, but the class the button gets is "color btn btn-secondary".

Comment: Oh, sorry it's react bootstrap. I will update answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the color style property with Bootstrap class name.

```
  <Button
    className={status.statusSeverityDescription === "Good Service" ? 'btn-success' : 'warning'}>
       <h4>{status.statusSeverityDescription}</h4>

  </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Interstingly, your first answer with "className" worked, but "variant" doesn't.

Comment: So, I will revert. I thought you use react bootstrap

Comment: I should have mentioned yes, my fault. It is reactstrap.

Comment: So instead of className, you can use "color" property
color={status.statusSeverityDescription === "Good Service" ? 'success' : 'warning'}

Comment: Interestingly it fails if I use 'color' instead of 'className'. Your solution works for me though, so thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

for bootstrap

```
<Button className={status.statusSeverityDescription === "Good Service" ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-warning'}>Primary</Button>
```

for react-bootstrap
`react-bootstrab` button change based on a prop called `variant` as the docs says

the code might be like below

```
<Button variant={status.statusSeverityDescription === "Good Service" ? 'success' : 'warning'}>Primary</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that leads to this result in the compiled result:

<button variant="success" class="btn btn-secondary">Primary</button>

Buttons are grey. But thank you for your help.

EDIT: I believe it's because I am using react-strap, not react-bootstrap. Sorry for the confusion. I've amended the question.

Comment: You are welcome any time .. i think you only need to change variant to className and the names reactstrap provide for this